# Getting access to additional node information using CTE Recursion SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, recursion, timeout, common-table-expression

Background table data:

```
memberid sponsorid mailfirstname maillastname
1000     NULL      Foo           Chu
1001     1000      Foo1          Chu1
1002     1001      Foo2          Chu2
1003     1002      Foo3          Chu3
1004     1003      Foo4          Chu4
```

The script below prints out the member I'm currently on.  But I also want to print the sponsor information for that member at the same time.  So, currently I get:

```
Level memberid sponsorid mailfirstname maillastname
0     1000     NULL      Foo           Chu
...
2     1004     1003      Foo4          Chu4
```

but for the 1004 member, I also want their sponsor:

```
Level memberid sponsorid mailfirstname maillastname sponsorfname sponsorlname
2     1004     1003      Foo4          Chu4         Foo3         Chu3
```

Query:

```
WITH Heirarchy
AS
(
   SELECT 
      CONVERT( INT , 0 ) [Level],
      T1.memberid,
      T1.sponsorid,
      T1.mailfirstname,
      T1.maillastname
   FROM
      members T1
   WHERE
      T1.memberid = 20000283

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
      CONVERT( INT , ( TH.[Level] + 1 ) ) [Level],
      T1.memberid,
      T1.sponsorid,
      T1.mailfirstname,
      T1.maillastname
   FROM
      members T1
   INNER JOIN 
      Heirarchy TH ON TH.memberid = T1.sponsorid
)
SELECT * 
FROM Heirarchy 
ORDER BY level, maillastname
```

Comment: It's a **`Hierarchy`** (not a `heirarchy`) ...

Comment: Where do you store that "sponsor" information? You just need to join to that particular table, and select those column that you want to show in your query result

Answer (score 0):

It should help you

In script below I retrieve all members with their sponsors

```
WITH Heirarchy
AS
(
   SELECT 
      0 AS [Level],
      T1.memberid,
      T1.sponsorid,
      T1.mailfirstname,
      T1.maillastname,
      T1.mailfirstname AS sponsorfname,
      T1.maillastname AS sponsorlname
   FROM
      members T1
   WHERE
      T1.sponsorid IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      TH.[Level] + 1 AS [Level],
      T1.memberid,
      T1.sponsorid,
      T1.mailfirstname,
      T1.maillastname,
      TH.mailfirstname,
      TH.maillastname
   FROM
      members T1
   INNER JOIN 
      Heirarchy TH ON TH.memberid = T1.sponsorid
)
SELECT * 
FROM Heirarchy
ORDER BY level, maillastname
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a342b/1/0)